# Selenium Chrome driver failed to parse value of getElementRegion

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

I get the following error from chrome driver when running my selenium tests with chrome driver.  The test works fine with firefox.

> unknown error: failed to parse value of getElementRegion

Here's the code, it fails when trying to click the submit button.  I'm using selenium-standalone to run my server, specifying chromedriver with `selenium-standalone start --drivers.chrome.version=2.8` and webdriverIO

```
client
    .url(options.url)
    .setValue(usernameSelector, username)
    .setValue(passwordSelector, password)
    .click(submitBtnSelector)
```

Answer (score -2):

I solved the same problem by deleting the line `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false` in my conf.js file on my protractor configuration.