# Selenium Chrom driver : failed to parse value of getElementRegion

Tags: selenium, docker, symfony, selenium-chromedriver, behat

I try to implement some Automated User Test with Behat/Mink on Selenium in a Docker.
However, I received a "failed to parse value of getElementRegion" for some Element.
Do you have any clue where I should look to solve this problem ?

I try to launch this test with docker, on a Selenium's Container.
The Behat test try to access to a div inside a modal.

I can confirm that the text is visible on the screen, it's one of my previous line in the behat's file.

I wanted to try the solution describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977672/selenium-chrome-driver-failed-to-parse-value-of-getelementregion), however I don't have any conf.js in my project.

I try to see during the test if the id change (With a sleep juste before trying to click), however, I can manually see it.

I don't see any other solution that the one I linked before on Google.

My Script

```
@javascript @second
Feature: Builder Features
  In Order to use the website as an Builder
  I should be able to modify the roadmap

  Scenario: I can do click on the modal
    When I am on "/thispage"
    Then I should see "The Title who open the Modal"
    Then I click on ".form-check-label"
    Then I wait "1"
    Then I wait until "#generic-modal" load
    Then I should see "The title of the modal"
    Then I should see "The description of the modal"
    Then I click on "#check47"
    Then I press "Close the modal"
```

The PHP behind I click on :

```
    /**
     * @Then /^I click on "([^"]*)"$/
     */
    public function iClickOn($selector)
    {
        $page    = $this->getSession()->getPage();
        $element = $page->find('css', $selector);

        if (empty($element)) {
            throw new Exception("No html element found for the selector ('$selector')");
        }

        $element->click();
    }
```

The docker-compose's Selenium part

```
    selenium:
        image: selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:latest
        networks:
            app_tier:
                ipv4_address: 172.11.1.4
        environment:
        - SCREEN_WIDTH=1920
        - SCREEN_HEIGHT=1080
        ports:
        - "5900:5900"
        volumes:
        - "/dev/shm:/dev/shm"
        - "../features/file:/usr/share/tag/file/"
```

The Behat's Extension in behat.yml

```
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url: "http://172.11.1.3"
            sessions:
                javascript:
                    selenium2:
                        capabilities: {"browserName": "chrome", "browser": "chrome", 'chrome': {'switches': ['--whitelisted-ips']}, "marionette": true, "extra_capabilities": {"goog:chromeOptions":{"w3c":false,"args":["start-maximized", 'disable-dev-shm-usage', 'disable-extensions']}}}
                        wd_host: 'http://172.11.1.4:4444/wd/hub'
        Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
```

I should pass all the behat's script without any error.

However, this message appears :

```
    Then I click on "#check27"                                                                                # FeatureContext::iClickOn()
      unknown error: failed to parse value of getElementRegion
        (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.75)
        (Driver info: chromedriver=77.0.3865.40 (f484704e052e0b556f8030b65b953dce96503217-refs/branch-heads/3865@{#442}),platform=Linux 4.19.23-coreos-r1 x86_64) (WebDriver\Exception\UnknownError)
```

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: This has another possible answer: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/40321/chromedriver-driver-failed-to-parse-value-of-getelementregion-understanding

Comment: This suggests waiting for the element to be visible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58274561/having-issues-with-click-when-using-new-version-of-chromedriver-chrome-and-sele