# Having issues with click when using new version of chromedriver, chrome and selenium in c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using latest chrome 77.0.3865.90
I have tried chromedriver versions - 77.0.3865.4000, 76.0.3809.*
The code is in C#

I am finding an element on the page and doing click on it.  This used to work fine and I think after new chrome browser update (to 77.0.3865.90) i am getting this error for clicks :

unknown error: failed to parse value of getElementRegion\n  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90)"}

I tried using multiple chromedriver versions as above nothing seems to work.

```
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("imgSearchReceiver"))).Click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Load Selenium Extras to your solution.

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
var element = wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("imgSearchReceiver")));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  My original code was with sleep and it wasn't working so i changed it to this... so either way it is not working..  Please help !!!

Comment: can you cut and paste the html in your original message?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Thread.sleep(4000)`. Sometimes `WebDriverWait` doesn't work for some element you need hard wait, sleep is the best solution for it.

Comment: There are very few times when a thread sleep should ever be used. I have seen solutions with close to a 1000 thread sleeps and it just kills you automation run from a time perspective. It is better to wait for an element to be visible than using a thread sleep. Raj - If you debug it, what happens?

Comment: Well, there are situations where waiting till visibility of element doesn't work and I know Thread.sleep is the last thing to go with.